# How to get the EJBContext from Guice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, guice, guice-persist

I'm trying to create some integration tests for a j2ee application. The DAO layer requires a `EJBContext` so that it can call `context.getUserTransaction()` and `utx.begin()`. Using **Guice** i managed to get the `EngityManager` working. But the `EJBContext` is now null. Any ideas how to get this working.

```
@Resource
protected EJBContext context;
```

Comment: Mixing Injection frameworks is rarely a good idea ... I would try if CDIUtils or Arquillian are better matches for your test case. If you are just interested in "simulating" the injection, you also can try out needle4j, it uses reflection and auto-mocking to test ejb/cdi.